# TcpClient Xamarin Chat connected but cannot send message

Tags: c#, xamarin, tcp, chat

I wrote a server-client chat LAN app for windows PC using class TcpClient. It worked then I wanted to put Client app chat on android thanks to xamarin,
to connect PC and mobile.

Connecting process works:

```cs
private void buttonClickConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client = new TcpClient();
    IPEndPoint IP_End = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"), int.Parse("13000"));
    try
    {
        client.Connect(IP_End);
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            textviewConversation.Text += "Connected to server" + "\n";
            STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            STW.AutoFlush = true;
            worker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            worker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

it connects to the server, but I cannot send messages. After the second message app crashes, it reads that thread is busy.

```cs
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)   
{
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        STW.WriteLine(text_to_send);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("send failed !");
    }
    worker2.CancelAsync();
}
```

There is no loop and the thread should just send it and and not block afterwards.
Find the full code [here](http://pastebin.com/DJxHUdXn).

Comment: you add the permission in the android manifest to the application can use internet and other permission in the device?

Comment: Try to create asynchronous method in Xamarin process to send the message.

Comment: Thank for reply. Yes I added many permissions; I dont know which actually i should, but I added many like ( wifi, internet...)

This client program on my windows 7 works. I copied it and little changed to xamarin (labels, buttons differences). I dont know why it doesnt work. I dont know how to put asynchronous method.

Comment: It looks like this: I click connect to server, it connects. Then send some message. It nothing happens. I send second and it crashes. It causes mult threading access error. Server gets some signal from client: it comes many many hundreds messages (then server crashes) but none of them is remarkable in string. All of them are empty. It's like cuting message by sharp knife and send small pieces of papper to server. If You have any new suggestions, please help me.And thanks a lot again.

Comment: watch this example https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/

Comment: thank, i solved little. I parted my program on small pieces. Just connect to server and send small message then quit. It works ! I changed technology lttle. I dont use TcpClient I used "byte[] buff = new byte[32];
            c.GetStream().Read(buff, 0, 32);" like that. It sends and sends back. Now I can extend my program to some chat or whatever. Thanks a lot for replies : )) !

Comment: Regards @Cenarius happy coding in Xamarin